# Cybereason just appeared on status bar

Tags: linux, xfce, manjaro, ransomware

I've been using Manjaro for a while, but last week a new icon appeared on the status bar. When right-clicking it says it is from Cybereason (see below), but I did not install it. Try to figure out where it comes from, but no good...

Any idea of what this might be and how to remove it?
Thanks,

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you add whether this is a corporate computer and if it's managed by your IT organization?

Comment: No, it is a personal computer managed only by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Citrix to connect to a remote server and, it seems, it was a program being deployed remotely by them.